# How do i Generate different calculations depending on what item is selected in drop down box?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, splist, dropdown

Hi guys I am making a SP 2013 site and am currently creating columns...

I have a drop down column (Circuit Type) , four text fields (Num1, Num2, Num3, Num 4) and a calculated column (Loss).

The Circuit Type dropdown has 5 different values. (ISDN, HDSL, HDSL2, HDSL4, Other).

The user choices a value and types a number in each text field and then the calculation appears....

but if user clicks on Circuit Type "ISDN" the calculation for "LOSS" will be Num1+Num2

but if the user clicks Circuit Type "HDSL" the calculation for "LOSS" will be different, same for the each of the different circuit type values..

How would I go about the certain calculation to happen depending on what Circuit Type the user chooses?

Im thinking of using designer workflow in SP Designer 2013, but not sure how to go about that.

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.. If you need more details I will reply back quickly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making `LOSS` column a `Calcuated` column. You can apply below formula

```
=IF([Circuit Type]="ISDN",[N1]+[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL",[N1]-[N2],0))
```

The syntax is `IF(condition, truestatement, falsestatement)`

In your case you can nest all the condition in multiple if's and use the `falsestatement` to specify else condition. Final formula will look like

```
=IF([Circuit Type]="ISDN",[N1]+[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL",[N1]-[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL2",[N1]*[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL3",[N1]/[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL4",[N1],0)))))
```

In the above `N1` and `N2` are field names. You should change it as required.

Comment: Do you have column with name `10`?

Comment: No Amal, 10 is just a number, so if the user chooses ISDN, the calculation 10+10 will happen which outputs 20.. am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, in that case you should not use square brackets just use 10 + 10 Or you can directly place the result as 20

Comment: Thank you, how many calculations can I put in one calculated column?    Also if what if HDSL, HDSL2, HDSL4 have the same calculation and ISDN has a different one?

Comment: for example, the calculation for HDSL, HDSL2, and HDSL4 is  = ((len_26 + dlen_26) * 3.88) + ((len_24 + dlen_24) * 2.84) + ((len_22 + dlen_22) * 2.18) + ((len_19 + dlen_19) * 1.5) + ((f1_bt + f2_bt) * 3) + nogachf1 + nogachf2;

Comment: while the calculation for ISDN is = ((len_26 + bt_26 + dlen_26 + dbt_26) * 2.81) + ((len_24 + bt_24 + dlen_24 + dbt_24) * 2.03) + ((len_22 + bt_22 + dlen_22 + dbt_22) * 1.42) + ((len_19 + bt_19 + dlen_19 + dbt_19) * 0.84);             of course the fields such as len_22 and bt_22 are in my database already...