# Question on SP 2013 calculation

Tags: spweb

reguarding this questiong [How do i Generate different calculations depending on what item is selected in drop down box?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122333/how-do-i-generate-different-calculations-depending-on-what-item-is-selected-in-d)

How would I do this calculation?

while the calculation for ISDN is = ((len_26 + bt_26 + dlen_26 + dbt_26) * 2.81) + ((len_24 + bt_24 + dlen_24 + dbt_24) * 2.03) + ((len_22 + bt_22 + dlen_22 + dbt_22) * 1.42) + ((len_19 + bt_19 + dlen_19 + dbt_19) * 0.84); of course the fields such as len_22 and bt_22 are in my database already...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.81) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.42) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.84)
```

**Updated based on comment**

```
=IF([Circuit Type]="ISDN",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.81) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.42) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.84),IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL",[N1]-[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL2",[N1]*[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL3",[N1]/[N2],IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL4",[N1],0)))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this did work for me, but I have a question, is it possible to do two calculations when the user chooses a selection... so if ISDN is chosen, I want variable1 to do this calculation var1 =(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.81) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.42) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.84) and then var2=(([pen_26] + [pt_26] + [plen_26] + [pbt_26]) * 2.81) + (([pen_24] + [pt_24] + [plen_24] + [pbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([pen_22] + [pt_22] + [plen_22] + [pbt_22]) * 1.42)

Comment: @MattLudwig see my edit

Comment: Thankyou Bhai I will add another calculated column, and for the first column if I am doing a if statement will it go like this?                  =IF([Circuit Type]="ISDN (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.42) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.84),IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL",[len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [bt_26]) * 100) + (([len_24] + [t_24] + [len_24] + [bt_24]) * 200),IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL2",[len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [bt_26]) * 1.58) + (([len_24] + [t_24] + [len_24] + [bt_24]) * 2.3))) LIKE THAT?

Comment: did I do the )))) at the end correctly?